# My app is failing in Custom Adapter for ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

My app is failing in custom Adapter for `ListView`.

I am writing an app in Android where I want to show `ListView` in 3 columns.
I created an adapter for a `ListView`and my app is failing on the command:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `listView` is a `ListView` and `adapter` is a subclass of Adapter I created.
I know the problem is with my definition of the adapter and I want to look for a problem, but where to look for?

Here is a log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.NullPointerException   
at com.hayored.memory_helper.SearchActivity.search(SearchActivity.java:156) 
at com.hayored.memory_helper.SearchActivity.onClick(SearchActivity.java:120)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the full code for us to better understand the problem

Comment: you should add more code from your binding context and the adapter

Comment: Whatever object you're trying to use at line 156 in SearchActivity.java is null

Comment: if the problem line really is listView.setAdapter(adapter); then your listview is null so hasnt been found correctly. But the stacktrace you have here doesnt tell us much without the onsearch method posted

Comment: Thanks for answering - but I am just looking for a hint what can be wrong in listView.setAdapter(adapter); command.This is a long code, I based my code on http://techlovejump.com/android-multicolumn-listview/ so obiously I have to check again the definition of my adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem - in my Java program in the command `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`
listView was not defined as ListView type on my xml file.
My app has few screens and on each screen few buttons and text views, so my conclusion is: each item on the screen will have the name:xxx_yy_abcd where xxx is the name of the screen, yy - type of the item (tv - TextView, bt - button etc) and abcd the name of the item. I hope this way will prevent me from similar mistakes.